# Using the same condition for multiple datasets

Tags: loops, sas, conditional-statements, case, sas-macro

My code is as follows:

```
%macro xx(date);
proc sql;
create table test_&date as
select a.*
from population_&date as a
left join new_acct_no as b on a.names = b.names and put(intnx('month',input(put(&date,8. -l),yymmn6.),0,'e'),yymmdd10.) between b.birthdate and b.marriage_dt
left join old_acct_no as c on a.names = c.names and put(intnx('month',input(put(&date,8. -l),yymmn6.),0,'e'),yymmdd10.) between c.birthdate and c.marriage_dt
; 
quit;
%mend;
%date(201812);
```

I would like to make my code cleaner by replacing "`put(intnx('month',input(put(&date,8. -l),yymmn6.),0,'e'),yymmdd10.)`".

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: What type of variables are BIRTHDATE and MARRIAGE_DT?  Your code is treating them has character strings.

Comment: Are you sure the logic is right?  What if MARRIAGE_DT is 15DEC2018?  That is in the month of DEC2018, but will not get a hit since it is before the end of the month

Comment: @tom yes, i am treating the dates as character. 2018-12-31 between birthdate and marriage_dt.

Answer (score 1):

Place the result of the static computation in a new symbol before the `Proc SQL`.
Also, use the correct macro name when invoking it.  You defined `xx` and are invoking `date`

Example:

```
%macro Population_For(date);

%local this_month next_month;

%let this_month = %sysfunc(inputn(&date,yymmn6.));
%let next_month = %sysfunc(intnx(month,&this_month,1));

%put NOTE: SAS Date values &=this_month &=next_month;

proc sql check;
create table test_&date as
select a.*
from population_&date as a
left join new_acct_no as b on a.names = b.names and &next_month between b.birthdate and b.marriage_dt
left join old_acct_no as c on a.names = c.names and &next_month between c.birthdate and c.marriage_dt
; 
quit;
%mend;

%Population_For(201812);
```

The proper coding also depends on the how the date values are stored in the tables `new_acct_no` and `old_acct_no`.  Are they

- SAS date values
- Numeric of construct *yyyymmdd* (i.e. encoding year * 10000 + month * 100 + day)
- Strings of construct *yyyymmdd* or *yyyy-mm-dd*

NOTE: A date representation *`yyyy-mm-dd`* as rendered by SAS format `yymmdd10.` is interpreted in **other** data base systems queries as a date literal, not so in SAS.

**Date data stored as strings of construct *yyyy-mm-dd***

The lexicographic order of properly vetted YMD strings has the same order of the SAS date values they represent.

Thus such date data **could** be processed by computing and using a static `next_month` ymd representation if **both** tables store dates as YMD strings.  Such coding would remove the requirement to convert the date data in fields `birthdate` and `marriage_dt` to SAS dates during query time.

```
%local this_month next_month next_YMD;

%let this_month = %sysfunc(inputn(&date,yymmn6.));
%let next_month = %sysfunc(intnx(month,&this_month,1));
%let next_YMD   = %sysfunc(putn(&next_month, yymmdd10.));

%put NOTE: SAS Date values &=this_month &=next_month;

proc sql check;
create table test_&date as
select a.*
from population_&date as a
left join new_acct_no as b on a.names = b.names and &next_month between b.birthdate and b.marriage_dt
left join old_acct_no as c on a.names = c.names and &next_month between c.birthdate and c.marriage_dt
;
```

Comment: noted on the macro error!.. So under %sysfunc it would not recognise dates in terms of yyyy-mm-dd in characters? because the variables birthdate and marriage_dt are both in characters string format.

Comment: Correct, a SAS date value is the number of days from epoch 01JAN1960.  All other date representations would want to be converted to the corresponding SAS date value.  Some string representations and date encodings that are **supposed** to be such as *yyyymmdd* are somewhat amenable to direct equality comparators and operators such as `between` but could potentially contains representations or encodings that do not have concordance to an actual date.